# Prototype getStyle('height') function

Tags: prototypejs

On elements for which no style height has been set, will `getStyle('height')` return the actual height of the element?

The prototype doc simply states "This method looks up the CSS property of an element whether it was applied inline or in a stylesheet"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you want the actual height, use [`element.getHeight()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getheight)

Comment: I created a jsp with markup <div id="hello">hello</div> and with no css.

Firebug console tells me 
$('hello').getStyle('height') = "11.0333px"
$('hello').style.height=""

Comment: @Angus - Depending on browser, prototype might be trying to use a computed style, but across browsers I would definitely stick to getHeight.

Answer (score 0):

it is also worth noting that element.getHeight() will only return an accurate value in IE on window.load() where as in Firefox and other modern browsers it will be available from dom:ready